# Should a RecyclerView remember its position when being recreated after poping the backstack?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a Fragment, that I replace with a transaction with a new one

That Fragment contains a RecyclerView with a big number of items.

When the user presses the finish button on the new fragment I pop the backstack, and the old fragment is recreated.

This causes the OnCreateView method to be called again and everything works fine with that.

My problem is that the RecyclerView in it is recreated, the adapter is reset, but it seems to automatically move to the position that it left (which I assumed would only happen if I used transaction add not transaction replace)

As a side note the adapter still calls OnBindViewHolder and OnCreateViewHolder for the visible items.

My question is , why does this happen? since the whole fragment is recreated shouldn't it reset to the first position? Other than manually calling scrollToPosition(0) before loading the new fragment, is there another way to make the fragment not remember anything and be actually fully recreated when returning ?

Comment: where in the fragment you are adding the data to the  adapter

Comment: can you try adding `android:saveEnabled="false"` on the `RecyclerView`?

Comment: @Melad after the cnCreateView is executed, I create a new adapter and the constructor contains the items that should be shown

Comment: @GennadiiSaprykin I will try it, thanks, see how it goes

Comment: The Fragment has its lifecycle with onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState, RecyclerView implements the functionatily to restore it state, I view this behaviour as good since the user will not get lost for getting on the first item on all back navigations (also if he missclick return he will see the item it intended to right in the way)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The LinearLayoutManager stores the scroll position in onSaveInstanceState. Since the SavedState parcelable is stored with the view id, as long as the position is not out of bounds while returning from the backstack, the scroll position is restored.

Comment: Is there a way to avoid this happening when using the linear layout Manager? A way to avoid storing scroll positions maybe?